# No aparece consulta en Android

Tags: android

tengo un problema intoento hacer una consulta e imprimirla en un Edit Text. Pero me aparece un mensaje en el Edit Text en lugar de que me aparezca mi consulta. Este es mi metodo para hacer la consulta.

```
public String[] ob_lab(){
    objBD = new Bd(nContext, "Laboratorios", null, 1);
    db = objBD.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Descripcion FROM Laboratorios WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Laboratorios);", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        names.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Descripcion")));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);
}
```

en este otro lo llamo para imprimirlo

```
public class consulta extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_consulta);


    TextView Lab=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lab_con);
    ConexionBD O1=new ConexionBD(this);
    O1.ob_lab();
    Lab.setText(O1.toString());
```

y me aparece esto en el TextView

!(https://postimg.org/image/6jbhn7etp/)

[image: Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu metodo `onLab()` devuelve un array tipo `string` por lo tanto, debes asignar en una variable de ese mismo tipo el resultado de tu llamada

```
String[] resultado = O1.ob_lab();
```

Luego buscas en esa variable `resultado` dl valor que tu quieras por ejemplo `resultado[0]` pero tu arreglo tienes muchos valores por lo tanto debes verificar que valor quieres.

Y finalmente

```
Lab.setText(resultado[0]);
```

**EDICION**

Al ver tu query me doy cuenta que buscas el valor descripcion de tu ultimo laboratorio guardado en la base de datos, por lo tanto eliminaria tu `while` de tu metodo y cambiaria el retorno de tu funcion a un solo valor, `string`

```
public String ob_lab(){
    objBD = new Bd(nContext, "Laboratorios", null, 1);
    db = objBD.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT Descripcion FROM Laboratorios WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Laboratorios);", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    string descripcion = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Descripcion"));
    cursor.close();
    return descripcion;
}
```

Y finalmente

```
Lab.setText(ob_lab());
```

Comment: me podrias explicar como busco la variable por favor, porque no entiendo esa parte, la columna que quiero de la consulta es la 2.

Comment: Actualice la respuesta.

Comment: me funcionó. muchas gracias

Comment: Saludos! @oscarramirez